# 2 if in jquery script to valid form

Tags: jquery

I have a form with two radio input.
For one of these two radio input (type1) I display 2 input text.
I would like before submiting the form to check if minimum one of these 2 input text boxes is not empty.
But my script doesn't work.

***HTML***

```
<input id="type1" value="1" type="radio">
<input id="num1" value="" type="text">
<textarea id="numlist"></textarea>
<input id="type2" value="1" type="radio">
```

***JQUERY***

```
$('#form2').on('submit', function (e) {
    if ($("input:radio[id=type1]").is(":checked")) {
        var comment2 = $('#numliste').val();
        var comment1 = $("#num1").val();
        if ((comment1.length === 0) || (comment2.length === 0)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('You have to write on minimum one input text');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `'#numliste'` should be `'#numlist'`

Comment: Maybe you have an other problem related to your type="radio". You have to add the same `name` attribute for both type1 and type2 to make them act like "radios"

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#form2').on('submit', function (e) {
  var type1_checked = $("#type1").is(":checked");
  if (type1_checked) {
    var comment2 = $('#numlist').val();
    var comment1 = $("#num1").val();
    if ((comment1 == "") && (comment2 == "")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You have to write on minimum one input text');
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

**EDIT:** Also I assume you want the radio buttons to act like options, so you need the property name. See below for an example (I changed the radio values too):

```
<form id="form2">
  <input name="options" id="type1" value="type1" type="radio">
  <input id="num1" value="" type="text">
  <textarea id="numlist"></textarea>
  <input name="options" id="type2" value="type2" type="radio">
</form>
```

Which allows to improve the  jquery code

```
$('#form2').on('submit', function (e) {
  var radio_value = $("input[name=options]:checked").val();
  if (!radio_value)
  {
    alert("Choose an option !");
    return false;
  }
  if (radio_value == "type1")
  {
    var comment2 = $('#numlist').val();
    var comment1 = $("#num1").val();
    if ((comment1 == "") && (comment2 == "")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You have to write on minimum one input text');
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: you could simplify the test to `if (!comment1 && !comment2)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo in 
`var comment2 = $('#numliste').val();` change it to "numlist"
And if you want this work you have to change the `||` to `&&` in if statement.

Answer (score -1):

i think this will work

```
$('#form2').on('submit',function (e) {
    if($("input:radio[id=type1]").is(":checked"))
              {
                var comment2 = $('#numliste').text();
                var comment1 = $("#num1").text();
                if((comment1.length === 0) || (comment2.length === 0))
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('You have to write on minimum one input text');
                    return false;
                }
              } });
```

Comment: `minimum one of these 2 input text boxes is not empty`. With your code, the form won't be submitted if one of the text box is empty. You need an `and` not an `or`

Comment: No, you still need an and.

Comment: Yes, and that's what we want. With your code, if one condition is true (one input is empty, not the other), the form won't be submitted. This is in contradiction with "minimum one is not empty".